# The regression equation for this data?

Tags: statistics, regression, data-analysis

I am trying to fit an equation to the data pictured. I want my students to be able to graph a y= equation. I have several different sets that all have a similar look to them. The pink graph I drew was just a guess but it kind of looks like a normal curve that is skewed. What would an equation be that might fit this data.
(For reference, the x-axis tick marks are intervals of 50 and the y-axis tick marks are intervals of 1.)

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#/media/File:Poisson_pmf.svg -- take a look at $\lambda = 1$

Comment: Yeah but I'm looking for a y= equation that my students could graph.

Comment: Then you need to include all the necessary information in your question.  The community should not work harder than you just to understand what exactly you need.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment.** I have to say that this is an astonishingly unmotivated exercise.
It is difficult to know how to take a useful approach to the curve-fitting.
I used Minitab to fit a cubic regression equation. The resulting curve and
(wide) prediction interval are shown below. The cubic equation is
shown in the header. (A quadratic equation won't fit at all.
I suppose there is a 10th degree polynomial that would fit "perfectly".)

[image]